# La busqueda de pagos no trae todos los pagos

Tags: php, mercadopago

Estoy usando la libreria PHP y al hacer un

```
    $filters = array(
            "id"=>null,
            "site_id"=>null,
            "external_reference"=>null,
            "range" => "date_created",
            "begin_date" => "NOW-1MONTH", //2017-07-01T00:00:00Z
            "end_date" => "NOW", //NOW
            //"status" => "approved",
            //"operation_type" => "regular_payment"
    );
    $searchResult = $mp->search_payment($filters, 0 , 1000);
```

Los pago no llegan a mil y no incluye algunos pagos correctos que se realizaron hace 10 dias pero si trae mucho mas viejos
A alguien se le ocurre que puede ser?
Gracias!

Comment: Adrian, bienvenido a SOes. Por normal general, te recomiendo hacer el [tour]. Mercadopago tiene una extraña politica de redirigir a sus usuarios aqui, sin embargo, [no somos el soporte de ellos](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2525/por-qu%c3%a9-no-somos-soporte-al-cliente-de-tu-compa%c3%b1%c3%ada-favorita/2526#2526). SI tu pregunta tiene que ver con php, quizas si podremos ayudarte, de lo contrario, trata de contactarles directamente a ellos.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que te sucede es que estas pidiendo muchos resultados. Tenes que paginarlos. Por defecto la API de Mercadopago devuelve 30 pero no puede superar cierto límite. A mi me paso lo mismo y paginando obtuve los resultados.
Espero te sirva. Saludos!

Comment: Además podes ordenarlos por fecha, para por ejemplo obtener los ultimos pagos en primer lugar...

Comment: Para que tenga mayor posbilidad de ser aceptada tu respuesta pon un ejemplo con código